# Google Guice Depedency Injection - Where exactly the object is created?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have the below code in which i dont understand where exactly the new instance of EmailService is created.  I tried to check many other stackoverflow conversations, but still couldnt get it clearly.

```
public interface MessageService {
    void sendMessage(String msg, String recipient);
}

@Singleton
public class EmailService implements MessageService {

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String msg, String recipient) {
        System.out.println("Sending Email to"+recipient+"Msg is:" + msg);
    }
}

public class MyApplication {
    private MessageService service;

    @Inject
    public MyApplication(MessageService service) {
      this.service = service;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String msg, String recipient) {
        this.service.sendMessage(msg, recipient);
    }
}

public class AppInjector extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(MessageService.class).to(EmailService.class);
    }

}

public class ClientApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector());
        MyApplication app = inj.getInstance(MyApplication.class);
        app.sendMessage("How are you?", "hello@hello.com");
    }
}
```

nowhere in this code, new instance of class EmailService is created something like (new EmailService()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Via reflection Guice analyzes `MyApplication`'s constructor and finds out that it depends on `MessageService` (`public MyApplication(MessageService service)`). Exactly this constructor is taken because it is marked with `@Inject`
2. Guice tries to find out binding for this interface. In `AppInjector` you specified that implementation for `MessageService` is `EmailService` (`bind(MessageService.class).to(EmailService.class);`)
3. `EmailService` is instantiated via [Java Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). It is done via [`Class.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html)
4. After `EmailService` is created, it is passed as a parameter to `MyApplication.class.newInstance()` factory.

Notes:

- By default, if you have not specified any additional constructor, there is a default one without parameters, that's why `EmailService` has not dependencies.
- `EmailService` instance is a singleton because it is marked with `@Singleton`, so if there will be more dependencies on it, exactly the same instance will be injected
- If you would like to create [binding to instance](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InstanceBindings), you can use the following code: `bind(MessageService.class).toInstance(new EmailService());`
- Google libraries are always rich in terms of documentation. I advice you to read through this wiki: [google/guice/wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted)